# jquery validate interdependent PAIR of FIELDS

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to validate a set of name , mobile number fields in a form. For convenience on the serverside script, I've named the fields with array notation (i.e., with square brackets).
Also, the same html below repeats itself a number of times depending on how many records are required.

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
 <tr><td class="b_name"><label>Name <sup>*</sup></label></td><td class="b_mobile"><label>Mobile <sup>*</sup></label></td><td class="removetext"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removebroadcast(this);" id="remove_<?php echo $cnt;?>">Remove</a></td></tr>
 <tr><td class="b_name" id="name_<?php echo $cnt;?>"><input type="text" value="" name="broadcast_name[]" class="broadcast_name" /></td><td class="b_mobile" id="mobile_<?php echo $cnt;?>"><input type="text" value="" name="broadcast_mobile[]" class="broadcast_num" /></td><td id="message_<?php echo $cnt;?>">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

On the rules/messages part so far, I've come up with:

```
'broadcast_name[]':{required:function(element){
                    return $(element).parent().next().children('input').val()!='';
                }
            },
'broadcast_mobile[]':{required:function(element){
                    return $(element).parent().prev().children('input').val()!='';
                }
            },
```

However, this does only work for the first set of name / mobile fields. I tried a few other tricks too (e.g., used $.each type validation, used a custom rule function etc.) but none of them seemed to work. Is there anything I am doing wrong here? Please help! :(

Answer (score -1):

you may want to check out this for the phone field: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

and can't you do something like

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    var errors = false;
    $(this).find('input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() === ''){
            errors = true;
        }
    });
    if(errors){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('errors exist');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the mask plugin, but I've actually been using it on the phone field, just didn't think it would be necessary to give detail on everything. 
Regarding the solution provided - I need to use jquery validation plugin in specific, apologies if that wasn't clear to you earlier.

Comment: you're welcome, i'm wondering why my answer doesn't work for you though